# no navigation pop up error in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am making ipad app and I am using navigation controller for navigate,
initially I hides the naviagtion controller but I used segue for navigation.

When I tap on button it perform segue and go to next view but there were a pop up open and display

```
NO naviagtion,Navigation error!"
```

NO Navigation error Pop up open when goes to next view in ios.

Comment: You are embedded UInaviagtioncontroller as initial view controller?

Comment: No, i am embeded navigation controller a newly created loginViewController , when i start at that time i used but now i change it and embeded with secondviewcontroller

Comment: what type of segue is this? Is that segue performing a push in you navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

[image: set it to Initial View Controller]

Select UInavigationcontroller in Story board and set it to Initial View Controller